# Retrieve Chrome URL and use in conjunction with another fixed URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am currently writing a chrome extension so that I have a button on the bar and when clicked I wanted it to grab the URL of the currently selected tab and open a new tab as follows:

FixedURL/grabbedURL ex: lets say the currently opened page is "http://www.abc.com" and the fixed url I assign is "http://www.123.com" so the new URL I want to be opened will be http://www.123.com/http://www.abc.com

This way only the second part of URL opened in a new tab will change depending on the selected tab.

I already created a manifest.json and the icons, title, etc...

I then tried to use both background.html and popup.html but to no avail.

I also am kinda lost on the whole .js file thing and how to link all of them together.

The maximum I could achieve is having chrome open:
chrome://settings/extensions/obidbojnjbigokbpalmaacmgmecopond/title.url
when I clicked the button.

Here is my manifest.json

```
   {
  "name": "Circumvent",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Opens new tab",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "111.png",
      "default_title": "Circumvent!",
      "popup": "main.html"
         },
  "icons": {
      "48": "111.png"
   },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","notifications","http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Any idea of what a sample code will look like and/or a brief clarification would be really awesome and very helpful!

Thanks in advance....

P.S. my first extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) and have it listen for clicks on your extension's [browser action button](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url" : "http://www.123.com/" + tab.url})
});
```

(This code goes in your background page.)

You'll need to remove the `popup` line in your manifest, since the `onClicked` handler won't fire if there's a popup (and besides, you don't want a popup, you just need a button).

Comment: Perfect!!! It did the trick thanks very much! But if I were to add that it closes the tab it grabbed the URL from before opening the new one what will I need to add?

Comment: Using `chrome.tabs.update` will use the current tab instead of making a new one. If you really want close the tab and open a new one (maybe you want a new tab with no history), use `chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);` before the call to `chrome.tabs.create`.

Comment: Thanks again chrome.tabs.update was just fine and I really didn't want to complicate just to avoid the tab having history.